# Is there a way to convert AbstractBackEndDataProvider to ListProvider?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have written a custom https://mindbug.in/vaadin/vaadin-dataprovider-example/ CallBackDataProvider that I based on this link here, which is used for a multi-select combo box (an addon https://github.com/bonprix/vaadin-combobox-multiselect from Vaadin's addon directory) for the purpose of providing a item lazy loading.

According to the addon's clear() and selectAll(), it expects a ListDataProvider. I've already set the component's data provider to used the custom data provider above. Whenever a clear or selectAll function is triggered, the Class Cast Exception is being thrown. It is expecting a ListDataProvider.

The very straightforward workaround for this case is to disable the clear and selectAll method by setting the boolean flag to false, but from the user's point of view, this will not be flexible.

Another step attempted is to to convert the stream into a Collection List, yet, it didn't work. It still throws an error.

This is the custom CallbackDataProvider, extended from the AbstractBackendDataProvider:

```
    public ItemDataProvider(ReceiptService receiptService) {
        if(receiptService != null){
            this.receiptService = receiptService;
        }else {
            this.receiptService = new ReceiptService();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Stream<SkusSelectBox> fetchFromBackEnd(Query<SkusSelectBox, String> query) {
        stream = receiptService.fetchSkus(query.getFilter().orElse(null), query.getLimit(), query.getOffset(), query.getSortOrders()).stream();
        return stream;
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeInBackEnd(Query<SkusSelectBox, String> query) {
        return receiptService.countSkus(query.getFilter().orElse(null));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getId(SkusSelectBox item) {
        return item.getItemId();
    }

    public Stream<SkusSelectBox> getStream(){
        return stream;
    }
```

The SkuSelectBox is a simple two string attribute object that retrieves the id and the name.

For this component, I have set the following at the view page:

```
ItemDataProvider itemDataProvider = new ItemDataProvider(receiptService);

        ComboBoxMultiselect<SkusSelectBox> skuSelect = new ComboBoxMultiselect<>("Items");
        skuSelect.setPlaceholder("Choose Items");
        skuSBox.add(new SkusSelectBox("0", "No data found"));
        skuSelect.setWidth(80, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        skuSelect.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);
        skuSelect.setItemCaptionGenerator(SkusSelectBox::getItemName);
        skuSelect.setSelectAllButtonCaption("Select All");
        skuSelect.setClearButtonCaption("Clear");
        skuSelect.showSelectAllButton(true); 
        skuSelect.showClearButton(true);
        skuSelect.setDataProvider(itemDataProvider);
        skuSelect.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
        skuSelect.isReadOnly();
        skuSelect.setPageLength(20);
        if(skuSBox.size() <=1 ){
           skuSelect.showSelectAllButton(false);
           //skuSelect.showClearButton(false);
        } 

        skuSelect.setResponsive(true);
```

The selectAll and clear methods are very similar except for the very end of the method:

```
@Override
        public void selectAll(final String filter) {
            final ListDataProvider<T> listDataProvider = ((ListDataProvider) getDataProvider());
            final Set<String> addedItems = listDataProvider.getItems()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(t -> {
                        final String caption = getItemCaptionGenerator().apply(t);
                        if (t == null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return caption.toLowerCase()
                                .contains(filter.toLowerCase());
                    })
                    .map(t -> itemToKey(t))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            updateSelection(addedItems, new HashSet<>(), true);
            updateSelection(new HashSet<>(), removedItems, true); (this is for clear method)
        }
```

Basically the class cast exception is shown in this error message, referring to either the clear or selectAll, whichever method I was invoking:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.igi.sycarda.dashboard.hib.utils.ItemDataProvider cannot be cast to com.vaadin.data.provider.ListDataProvider
    at org.vaadin.addons.ComboBoxMultiselect$1.clear(ComboBoxMultiselect.java:224)
```

I'm looking at the selectAll or clear method, when invoked to work as usual as if not using a CallbackDataProvider.

Until the next patch release for the addon is released, I need to put in a workaround for this problem, how can I convert a custom provider to a ListDataProvider either in a quick dirty way or a cleaner way if required?

**UPDATE**: Normally, I would do a direct fetch from the service class, but when tested with a tenant that has about 20K of item records, the loading of the page and the specific component box is quite slow to load. That CallbackDataProvider is to test this will work for those big amount of records.

Answer (score 0):

The idea with a list data provider is that all items are loaded into memory. It is possible to load all items from a database into memory and then use that to create a list data provider. This does on the other hand defeat the purpose of having a callback data provider.

It's probably more straightforward for you to fetch the items into a list directly from your `receiptService` rather than going through the existing data provider.

Comment: Yes, I agree that I would prefer fetching directly from the receiptService class. The reason of testing out the custom data provider was to test the lazy loading for big tenants with a high record count. For example, when the normal straightforward fetching process was tested for Tenant T,  (about 20K product records), the loading of the combo item was awfully slow, even when you type a few characters to filter into it. Note: this will be updated in the original post.

Comment: There is no sensible way of having a `ListDataProvider` that does lazy loading since a list data provider is by definition non-lazy. You'd either have to load everything into memory or wait until there's an update to the add-on component.

Comment: Seems that we need to emphasize on the benefits of SQL views to help with the fetching into memory process.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are restrictions or blocks that cause error to approach I was doing, someone just suggested to me to create a view derived from the tables / columns required and used them instead of the normal tables.

After creating a view, I just reverted and removed these lines below to the usual implementation:

```
skuSelect.setDataProvider(itemDataProvider);
        skuSelect.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
        skuSelect.isReadOnly();
        skuSelect.setPageLength(20);
        if(skuSBox.size() <=1 ){
           skuSelect.showSelectAllButton(false);
           //skuSelect.showClearButton(false);
        }
```

At the time of writing this, we've tested it an hour ago and it solves the problem without sacrificing the performance time taken and creating an additional component. In terms of time measurement, a 20K result set in a view loads in less than 10 seconds vs 7-9 minutes previously.